# Syntax Error <expression Line 1>

Tags: python-3.x, syntax

I'm trying to convert a date in a string format (13/06/2017) into a date format June 13, 2007. I have written the code but I keep getting a syntax error for my first line which is the definition of the function line.

My code is this:

```
def printDate(date):
    import datetime
    newdate = datetime.strptime(date, %d/%m/%Y)
    d = newdate.strftime(%b %d, %Y)
return d
```

Comment: Date formatters are strings, `%d/%m/%Y` without quotes makes no sense (there's your syntax error).

Comment: Oops I had the quotes in my code, just fogot them when I typed out the question. Yeah still got the syntax error still in line one.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass the parameter "date format" as a string, that's why, also be sure to import datetime module as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
def printDate(date):
     newdate = datetime.strptime(date, "%d/%m/%Y")
     d = newdate.strftime("%B %d, %Y")
     return d
```

Test:

```
printDate("13/06/2017")
>> 'June 13, 2017'
```

Comment: How do I pass the parameter "date format" into a string? Do I write string in front of the parameter like
   def printDate(string(date)):?
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm talking about when you call the functions strptime and strftime, you must pass the date format as "%d/%m/%Y" and "%B, %d, %Y" you see? with quotes, the code that i pasted above should work normally..

Comment: I typed in your code into ArcGIS's field calculator and it still says I have a syntax error on line 1. Any idea on what it is?

Comment: Error 1: "There was a failure during processing, check the geoprocessing results window for more details".

Under geoprocessing results: "Error 000539 Syntaxerror: invalid syntax (<expression>, line 1)"

Comment: I believe that's a different question, i have no experience whatsoever with ArcGIS's and i'm not familiar with how it is supposed to run with python, even tho i'm completely sure that the code i provided, works, feel free to try it on python's console, please open another question with that specific problem.